# How we concatenate numeric result with a string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sum, subquery

I want to concatenate a result of float with a string object in MySQL
interface,

I wrote this query:

```
select name, concat(str(round(sum(amount_paid)/(select sum(amount_paid) from order_items)*100.0,2)) ,'%') as pct
from order_items
group by 1
order by 2 desc;
```

Can anyone give me a reliable query, as it seems I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

`str()` is not a thing in MySQL. `concat()` forces the conversion to string, so you can just do:

```
select name, 
    concat(
        round(
            sum(amount_paid) / (select sum(amount_paid) from order_items) * 100,
            2
        ), 
        '%'
    ) as pct
from order_items
group by name
order by pct desc;
```

Note that if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can make use of a window sum instead of a subquery:

```
select name, 
concat(
    round(
        sum(amount_paid) / sum(sum(amount_paid)) over() * 100,
        2
    ), 
    '%'
) as pct
from order_items
group by name
order by pct desc;
```

Comment: thanks @GMB, i tried concat without str, but it must be my virtual environment has some limitation.

Comment: @RakeshDash: what happened when you tried this solution?